# How to separate a line of code in node.js

Tags: node.js

I am a total noob to node.js and I am trying to separate a long line of code. The es-lint says it cannot be more than 80 characters . I do not want to turn off es-lint because it helps me ensure a clean deploy to firebase. Here is the code in it's entirety

```
exports.refresh = functions.https.onRequest((req, resp) => {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(req.body));
  const jsonObject = req.body;
  console.log("loginName");
  console.log(jsonObject["event"]["loginName"]);
  for (let i=0; i<jsonObject["event"]["data"]["providerAccount"].length; i++) {
    console.log(jsonObject["event"]["data"]["providerAccount"][i]["providerId"]);
  }
  resp.status(200).end();
});
```

The line of code that is in question is

```
console.log(jsonObject["event"]["data"]["providerAccount"][i]["providerId"]);
```

It's too long says es-lint.
I have tried

```
console.log(jsonObject["event"]["data"]["providerAccount"],
        [i]["providerId"]);
```

and

```
console.log(jsonObject["event"]["data"]["providerAccount"] +
        [i]["providerId"]);
```

and I get errors. So how do I properly break a one line code across multiple lines? Many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The square notation isn't required for nondynamic alphanumeric keys: you can simply replace

`console.log(jsonObject["event"]["data"]["providerAccount"][i]["providerId"]);`

With

`console.log(jsonObject.event.data.providerAccount[i].providerId);`

Or you can use variable to store providerAccount
Like this
`const providerAccounts = jsonObject.event.data.providerAccount;`

And later console like this:
`console.log(providerAccounts[i].providerId);`

From your question, it looks like you're new to NodeJS.

I'd suggest checking for existence in case nested objects aren't present something like
`if(jsonObject && jsonObject.event && jsonObject.event.data ...`
Since it'll be unhandled error if any key doesn't exist and you app might break.

Also, you can improve the for loop with iterators like map, forEach:

```
jsonObject.event.data.providerAccount.map(account => console.log(account.providerId));
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to dot notation, invoke the iterator instead of using an index-based `for` loop:

```
for (const item of jsonObject.event.data.providerAccount) {
  console.log(item.providerId);
}
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you for the tip! I found it extremely useful!